# How to ignore the word "the" when alphabetizing an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a function that alphabetizes my array of records perfectly by artist but a lot of the artists have the word "The" at the beginning of their name and I would like for the function to ignore "The" when it is there and alphabetize the word following it. Here is a snippet of my array and function :

```
var recordCollection = [{
  "artist": "The Beatles",
  "title": "The Beatles",
  "year": "1968",
}, {
  "artist": "Led Zepplin",
  "title": "II",
  "year": "1969",
}];


function alphabetize() {
  recordCollection.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.artist.toLowerCase(),
      nameB = b.artist.toLowerCase()
    if (nameA < nameB)
      return -1
    if (nameA > nameB)
      return 1
    return 0
  })
};
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: That seems like an odd requirement ... if the artist A name is `The Beatles` and another one is `At the Gates` you would sort `The Beatles` first?

Comment: The expected output is to have The Beatles come before Led Zeppelin for example. I have all of them outputting into a div into individual Bootstrap Cards with the titles, artist and album art and I want to have them organized alphabetically when searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could use a simple regular expression:

```
recordCollection.sort((a, b) => {
  const nameA = a.artist.toLowerCase().replace(/^the\s+/, '');
  const nameB = b.artist.toLowerCase().replace(/^the\s+/, '');
  return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
});
```

If you want it completely [*DRY*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you can even do:

```
recordCollection.sort((a, b) => {
  const [nameA, nameB] = [a, b].map(_ => _.artist.toLowerCase().replace(/^the\s+/, ''));
  return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
});
```

### Sample

```js
const recordCollection = [{
  "artist": "The Beatles",
  "title": "The Beatles",
  "year": "1968",
}, {
  "artist": "Led Zepplin",
  "title": "II",
  "year": "1969",
}];

recordCollection.sort((a, b) => {
  const [nameA, nameB] = [a, b].map(_ => _.artist.toLowerCase().replace(/^the\s+/, ''));
  return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
});

console.log(recordCollection);
```

- `/^the\s+/` will catch "the" followed by any number of spaces at the beginning of the string,
- [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) will compare the strings and return a negative value, positive value or `0` accordingly.

Note: used arrow syntax and `const`, you can easily switch back to `function() { ... }` and `var` if you need to support older clients / are not using something like Babel.

Comment: regex should be case insensitive.

Comment: @PalSingh I don't think that matters after `toLowerCase()` :)

Comment: Fare enough :)
However, I tried it in jsfiddle, The Beatles are still on index 1

Comment: @PalSingh Added a snippet to the answer. I'm getting it at index 0.

Comment: THIS WORKS! I just had to add a space in "/^the \" because it sorted them all first since the space was still in the front.